# An App ID with Identifier '' is not available. Please enter a different string

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store, provisioning-profile, app-id

I am trying to add a new APP ID to prepare for App Store submission and got the following error under the bundle ID I provided.

> An App ID with Identifier `'com.domainName.AppName'` is not available. Please enter a different string.

What does this mean? I am trying to add a brand new App ID, of course it does not exist.

What am I missing? I do not remember experience the problem last time I create an App ID.

Comment: Somebody registered AppID you've entered! Choose another one. This is my case.

Comment: In my case it is an app identifier that I own and use, yet I still get this message.

Comment: you might have already registered this app id

Comment: Removing and adding the account in XCODE  >PREFERENCES worked for me.

Comment: Just upload using latest Xcode version 7.3.1 worked for me like a charm. Thanks

Answer (score 116):

## update

As of Xcode 8, *iOS Team Provision Profile Managed by Xcode* are now **updated by Xcode automatically and correctly**. They are not even listed at the Developer Portal, but generated on-the-flight.

However, the solution proposed below will still work. I've switched to using the automatic provisioning profiles.

## tl;dr

Remove INVALID **iOS Team Provision Profile Managed by Xcode** from Developer Portal and manually create **iOS Developer Provision Profile**. Download it via Xcode and you should be good to go.

## details

### Problem:

I started to experience this after Xcode 7.3 (7D175).

What I did before the issue:

- renewed Certificates (developer & distribution) via Xcode, b/c of their expiration;
- installed two required certificates (developer & distribution) in my keychain;
- re-generated Ad Hoc and App Store Provision profiles at Developer portal with new distribution certificate;
- downloaded locally Ad Hoc and App Store Provision profiles via Xcode;
- walk the project [through the process of Setting up Xcode to automatically manage your provisioning profiles](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1814/_index.html)
- noticed iOS Team Provision Profile Managed by Xcode was **INVALID**
- saw Xcode being not able to Build & Run due to INVALID iOS Team Profile.

Tapping "Fix Issue" (<strike>the only way, I know to make provision profiles managed by Xcode valid</strike>), given the error `An App ID with Identifier '<app id>' is not available`.

### Solution:

I have:

- manually removed INVALID iOS Team Provision Profile Managed by Xcode from Developer Portal
- manually created iOS Developer Provision profile
- Downloaded it via Xcode

Now, I am able to Build & Run app to my devices.

Comment: wait what? We are supposed to not use the automatic xcode thing? what's the point of the xcode-style certificate if it can't be used for actual app store submission?

Comment: "They are not even listed at the Developer Portal, but generated on-the-flight." iTunes connect requires an app id, so if it "isn't even listed" then I can't upload my app to the app store!

Comment: If you created your project before with Xcode I think what happens is that recent versions of Xcode automatically create the AppId for you.
I was stuck with the same problem, then I realized:
 
* the AppId I was trying to create appeared in appstoreconnect when creating a new app and selecting the bundle ID. It was named "XC com domain appname - com.domain.appname";
* I couldn't see the ID in developer.apple.com because the scroll bar is hidden by default in Safari. Didn't see that there are more entries... Because all the ones created by Xcode start with XC, they appear at the bottom...

Comment: Didn't understand a lick of this.  What is Developer Portal first of all?

Comment: This may be correct, but is not usable for me. How does one do this stuff? Too high level.

Answer (score 75):

**TL;DR** Xcode is very particular about the **name** you give your App ID in the member center.  Having the correct bundle identifier is not enough.  You must use the specific format shown below for Xcode to "see" your App ID.

**Update**: According to @isaacselement in the comments below, this issue has been **resolved in Xcode 7.3.1**.

---

@romrom's solution of deleting the App ID and having Xcode create a new one was a clue.  Unfortunately it was a nonstarter for me since my App ID was used by a Store app and therefore could not be deleted.

However, I discovered through some experimentation that I could solve the problem by manually editing the exiting App ID.  It turns out that Xcode is really picky about the *name* of the ID, and not just the bundle ID.

For a typical bundle ID such as *com.mycompany.appname*, the App ID name must be in this format:

```
XC com mycompany appname
```

*a name in any other format won't be seen by Xcode*.

---

**How to check if you're affected / How to Fix**

1. Log in to the [Member Center](https://developer.apple.com/membercenter/).
2. Click on "Certificates, Identifiers & Profiles".
3. One the left-hand navigation bar, click on "App IDs".
4. Locate the App ID with your bundle identifier.
5. If that App ID doesn't have the correct name format (as shown above), click on it then click the Edit button.
6. Change the name and click Done.
7. Enjoy the reduction in stress and anger.

P.S. There are some related problems **if you're using Xcode 7.3** in which it won't automatically create proper distribution profiles for you, even if you fix the name as I mentioned above.  The solution is to downgrade to 7.2.1 or 7.3 Beta or use a tool like fastlane/sigh.

Comment: Got validation successful after applying this advice. I wish Apple guys did know how much time and nerve I pointlessly burned trying to figure out this crap. Thank you so much for posting it here!

Comment: This worked great! Saved me from making a call to Apple this was driving me nuts.

Comment: This worked for me. Just renamed AppID `XC com mycompany bundleIdentifier` and redownloaded all profiles after updating the invalid one.

Comment: Turned out I never created one for the app store :/  but this got me going, thanks!

Comment: I can't believe renaming the AppID had this much power, but that was the solution for me. Thanks for this.

Comment: An App ID with Identifier 'xxx' is not available. Please enter a different string.  (nope...7.3.1)

Comment: GENIUS! I tried every other answer, I also couldn't delete it, but by renaming the app Id it worked!

Comment: Renaming App ID in member center actually helped. Unbelievable. Thank you.

Answer (score 58):

I had the same issue and solved by following steps below:

1. Go to Xcode `Preferences` > `Accounts` > `Choose your Apple ID account`
2. Tap on `View Details`
3. Tap on `Download all` and then `Done`

However it was working fine earlier but I don't know the reason why it stopped suddenly. I have gone through the steps above and found it working properly.

Comment: Great,Good luck !!

Comment: That's it! Thanks!

Comment: This is great! One thing I will note for the people seeing this, my main issue was that I am not a paid apple developer, meaning i didn't pay the $99 yet. So the other fixes on the site couldn't apply to me but this did.

Comment: Keep it up,guys ! Happy Coding !!

Comment: 2 years later, this happens to me. im so glad i scrolled down to this answer! Lol thx @AmitAjmera

Comment: Downloading fixed the problem?? I get the error (app id not available) from the developer web site. How can downloading to my machine fix a problem on the server? You get the error from a local app? like xcode or something?

Answer (score 50):

You may have no app with that same ID, but someone else may. The IDs must be unique globally, and not only within your own apps.

Comment: thanks for replay, i have situation where i have newly created ipa with xx.xxx.xxxx bundleId, now i have to upload it to appstore with other account can i change ipa with new bundleId ?

Comment: Yes you can. There's also a way to transfer an app from one account to another, but I'm not familiar with that. You could search it if you need to maintain your app's stats from the AppStore.

Comment: I can't believe this was the problem...Apple didn't specify this in the error message.

Answer (score 46):

Solution for `Xcode 7.3`.

Go to

```
Member Center -> Certificates, Identifiers & Profiles -> Provisioning Profiles -> All
```

Member Center: https://developer.apple.com/membercenter

Find certificate for your `App ID`, it should be invalid, Edit, Select your `iOS` Distribution certificate, Generate. Go to:

```
Xcode -> Preferences -> Accounts -> View Details -> Download all
```

[image: Invalid certificate]

[image: Generate step]

Comment: worked for me, just need to regenerate provisioning profiles

Comment: Boom you are a god

Comment: Mine wasn't invalid. Still this solution worked for me.

Comment: Where is "Member Center" ?

Comment: Maybe this used to work, but today I think not. I see nothing listed under my https://developer.apple.com/account/resources/profiles/list

Answer (score 24):

I had this problem, too.  It turns out that the problem and solution are quite simple.  When an Xcode user runs an app on a device using their free personal account, the Bundle ID is registered to the personal account.  Then, when the user upgrades to a paid Apple Dev account and tries to create an App ID using that Bundle ID - the backend system thinks that Bundle ID has been taken.

Fill out the form here at this website: https://developer.apple.com/contact/submit/ under the "Certificates, Identifiers, Profilescategory”.  I did this and the problem was solved in less than 12 hours.  This was Apple’s emailed response: "When you install an app on a device from Xcode using your Personal Team, the Bundle ID is registered to that account. I have deleted the Bundle ID "com.AppVolks.Random-Ruby” so it can now be registered on your paid membership.”

Hope that helps!

Comment: Just walked the same path. My solution:
remove your free dev user from "Accounts" and create new app (bundle ID) with your paid one. 
Changing "team" after creation did not solve my problem.

Comment: @Alex22: if you created a new bundle ID, why would you need to do anything else? FWIW I don't know what it means to or how to: 'remove user from "accounts"'

Answer (score 22):

**Version 7.3 (7D175)**

The Application ID Name should be same as application bundle identifier, if you application bundle identifier is **com.abc.xyz** than the application ID name for this  bundle ID should be **XC com abc xyz**

[image]

*A name in any other format won't be seen by Xcode.*

Comment: What is XC com abc xyz? Can you explain it please. Is this Xcode command line? Please elaborate. Thanks

Comment: its just application ID Name

Comment: i understand that but what is XC?

Comment: oh man! i struggled for three days and finally this comes as a savior

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH!

Comment: Nice one. thanks.

Answer (score 21):

TARGETS->General->Identity

At first, modify the value of 'Bundle Identifier', so that it is different from the previous value.Then team chose 'None'. Xcode6~Xcode7.3.1. But this is only a temporary solution.

[image]

Comment: This is a bad idea if your app was already approved.  It will break updates.

Comment: First select "none", no problem running the project development and then select your account number on it.

Comment: @Oz Solomon: The question is about adding an app; initial submission; not an upgrade

Answer (score 15):

Same issue happened with me, it might be that Xcode automatically selected another team name, its solved by choosing my correct team name.
Good luck !

Comment: @blwinters, did u find solution?

Comment: @Vladislav I posted the solution already ! Go to your project settings to find out if the correct team is selected ! This issue has many solutions and might be caused by different things !

Comment: And here's how to choose the team name: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/ConfiguringYourApp/ConfiguringYourApp.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012582-CH28-SW2

Answer (score 12):

I got solution for this kind of problem by selecting this option at the time of build export.

[image]

Regularly I select second option for build export process but after installing Xcode 7.3 when I try to export build at that time I receive above error. After some sort of forum discussion, I conclude that I need to select last option now to export build.

I hope this information become helpful to other members of forum as well.

Comment: Hi siddharth as you said ,the same problem occurred for me in xcode 7.3 and followed your steps it works great,But may i know the reason why it is not working by selecting second option in xcode 7.3 and why should have to go for fourth option.

Comment: May be now apple want to go in more structural manner. I don't know actual reason behind this.

Comment: genius! and don't 'validate', click 'export' instead.

Comment: nvm this didn't work, you can only install through itunes if you don't validate

Comment: YES, Siddharth. for me, since April 4, 2016, i have to also specify 4th option. I am pretty sure it's because my provisioning profile is for "development" but a different resource is for "distribution". Therefore, rather recreate all these, for now i can zoom ahead as long as I do not select the 2nd option.

Comment: That also seems to work, By the way I have to set Automatic in provision Profile under Build Settings and Xcode managed to work at all :)

Comment: You save my life, thank god. I think Apple is more and more crazy. Other softwares updates make them better and better, but Xcode is worse and worse after each time update from Apple. We always have to face new challegnes after updating xcode, now I really scare of doing this. It's terrible

Answer (score 10):

If you've updated your profiles, and none of the other good answers are working for you, try selecting "**Use local signing assets**" when it asks you to "select a Development Team to use for provisioning:".  I'd made sure everything else was in order, but it still wasn't working.  Using local signing assets worked perfectly.

Edit: It looks like Xcode 7.3.1 fixes this issue.
"- Fixed an issue that could prevent the export of an ad-hoc build from an archive"

Comment: Perfect workaround ! Updating Xcode 7.3 caused this issue for me.

Answer (score 9):

I received the same error after a reinstall of the OS on my developer mac and upgrading to xcode 7.3.

The Download all -button was my savior.
[image]

Answer (score 8):

In my case, the problem was, that the identifier had **too few dots**.

`com.example.foo` wasn't accepted

`com.example.foo.bar` works

Comment: I doubt that. I assume the one with 2 dots was already taken, but the one with 3 dots wasn't

Answer (score 8):

I had the exact same issue.  My problem stemmed from beginning app development under a free developer account and then switching app development to subscription (paid) developer account.  The original free developer account already had registered the bundle identifier that your paid developer account is trying to use.

You can verify that this is the problem by going to Xcode -> Preferences -> Accounts ->  and then look under Team.  If you see both your free (personal) team and your new paid team both listed then your probably having the same issue I had.  The two teams are interfering with each other and you need to remove the free (personal) team now that you want to use your paid developer account.

Unfortunately, the only solution is to call apple development support at 1-800-633-2152 (US & Canada) and have them deactivate the free (personal) account from the app so that your paid developer account can register the bundle identifier.

Answer (score 7):

I faced the same problem when i upgraded my Xcode to 7.3 and it showed me the same error in every project.
The simplest solution that i found was to just the remove the apple account from Xcode and add it again.
        [image]

To remove just go to Xcode > Preferences > Select the account and click on - sign.

[image]
and to add click on + sign and add the apple ID corresponding to your app.

After you add the account your problem would be solved..
If in case this still doesn't work . Then perform a next step of regenerating the profile (just click edit and then generate ) and then downloading your provisioning profile again and run it. I bet that would work .

Hope this helps.
All the best

Comment: This does not work on Sierra and Xcode 7.3 When I try to delete the account, nothing happens. I click the minus to no avail.

Comment: I did this steps and restarted machine. then it is working fine.

Comment: m glad it helped you @AntonyRaphel :)

Answer (score 6):

I realize this couldn't have been the cause of the original problem, because Xcode 6 wasn't available then, but I'll leave the answer anyway in case it helps someone.

Xcode 6 now registers your bundle ID for you automatically, so you don't have to.  It'll be somewhere in the list on a line starting with "Xcode iOS App ID".

Comment: I wasn't able to find this. I ended up straying from a traditional Bundle ID in order to get my app submitted (had a conflict of errors and no logical resolution)

Answer (score 5):

In my case it wasn't letting me because I set bundle id in xcode project BEFORE creating online, so I changed temporarily in xcode, created online then changed back to normal in xcode.

Comment: This solved my problem as of October 2021.Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

When I experienced the "An app with identifier XXX is not available" error in trying to switch on iCloud support in Xcode's Capabilities tab, I found that I had to:

- Give my app an explicit custom bundle id,
- Register my app manually at the Member Center, explicitly requesting iCloud support entitlements there.

After that, switching on iCloud support in Xcode worked. So, I suggest trying the same thing. Sometimes, things work better when you do them at the Member Center.

Answer (score 4):

For me, the problem happened because I first created a new AppID and then created a new app with the bundle identifier of the AppID in iTunes Connect, and then tried to connect my development app with the AppID from within Xcode.

In this case, Xcode assumed that the AppID has already been registered by someone.

To resolve the issue, you first change the bundle identifier in your app (in iTunes Connect's MyApp section) to some temporary values (or if you don't have any, create a dummy AppID such as `com.yourcompany.testapp`), delete the AppID in *Certificates, Identifiers & Profiles* page, and try connecting it **from within Xcode**, not **from within *Certificates, Identifiers & Profiles***, by pushing the *fixing issue* button in Xcode.

Comment: Thanks for sharing. You saved my day.

Answer (score 4):

Update to Xcode 7.3.1, they have fixed this bug.

Comment: I started having this problem on July 22, than Updated to 7.3.1 and problem  disappeared. Other answers would probably right for that conditions. But currently, it is an XCode issue, and I hope other people recognize this answer and save their time. Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 3):

I just had this problem. This is my configuration:

I've got an iPhone Developer Certificate in a developer account (Apple Store) and an Enterprise account. These 2 certificates have the same name in my keychain: `iPhone Developer : firstName lastName`

I assume Xcode doesn't know which one to take and pick the wrong one.

I fix it by selecting the good one in Xcode > Build Settings > Code Signing.
It was previously set to iOS Developer.

Answer (score 3):

I had same problem and the quick fix is:

1. Remove bundle id from General tab of Xcode
2. Go to info.plist file and put bundle id for the Bundle identifier field.

Clean and run. That's it.

Answer (score 3):

Purge or Fix all of the invalid and expired provisioning profiles.  Even though they appeared to be unrelated.

We encountered this when we attempted to recompile an app that was previously working fine.  Nothing worked until we cleaned up the provisioning profiles.

Then click on "Download All" under the "Provisioning Profiles" area of the Apple Id account for the appropriate team.

Possibly related to XCode 7.3

Answer (score 3):

[image]

I had the same issue on submission process and solved by Selecting Appstore provision instead of AdHoc. Simple!!

Hope this helps. All the best :)

Comment: I need to create for Ad-hoc only because it is only for limited numbers users to test.Is there any other possible answer?.

Answer (score 3):

If you encountered this error while making an ad hoc deployment, this is now fixed in the XCode 7.3.1 release (May 3th, 2016) : https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/xcode/id497799835?ls=1&mt=12

> **Changelog 7.3.1 :**
>
> - Git updated to version 2.7.4 to improve security
> - Fixed an issue where turning off a capability in the Xcode editor could leave the entitlement enabled in the app bundle
> - **Fixed an issue that could prevent the export of an ad-hoc build from an archive**
> - Fixed a crash when importing localizations

Comment: Thanks a lot, this worked for me. Almost all of my apps had that problem. It's  incredible that Apple releases Xcode version that are THAT buggy...

Answer (score 3):

If nothing else works, which was the case for me, try making a new app id that is longer, more unique, and possibly add some numbers.

Worked for me.

Comment: This seems to be the sure-fire solution. Maybe annoying that one needs to create a new ID, but it's gonna work. Brute force :)

Answer (score 3):

This is for those who bump into the odd case I did, you **CANNOT** use the keyword `test` in the bundle id.

We were needing to test sharing data through the app group feature and the companion app wasn't developed yet so we simply changed the bundle identifier to test.APP_NAME instead of company.APP_NAME. We set up everything in iTunes Connect and nothing worked right. We then swapped the name to beta.APP_NAME and Xcode was able to manage the app id correctly again.

Normally to fix this issue, verify your provisioning profiles and App Id's have the correct settings, and if your still having trouble to to Xcode -> Preferences -> Accounts -> View Details -> Download All and you should be good.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 3):

None of the above answers helped me, but I just found the solution.

**For those who couldn't benefit from any of the above answers;**

I have 2 different teams as you see.

I noticed that I did debug before with other team and **Xcode automatically created an App ID** in second team's developer account.

I opened https://developer.apple.com/ for second team's account and **removed auto-created APP ID**

Then worked fine

[image]

Comment: how did u remove this? I am facing same issue with my free account  but I could not find any option to remove auto-created APP ID. Did u do this with paid account or free like me?

Comment: Hi dude, mine was paid account but I don't think the steps are different. I opened https://developer.apple.com/ website and I clicked "certificated, IDs, profiles" button in the menu on the left. Then clicked "identifiers", I realized there are 2 different identifiers for my app and removed auto-created one. You can click that identifier and you'll see a "remove button" at the top right.

Comment: Those options are not available for Free account. btw after struggling I have solved my problem and post my answer here also

Comment: Cool then. Good luck with your app

Answer (score 2):

This may only apply to the latest version of Xcode (7.3 D175), recently release:

> Press the `Try Again` Button

After several hours of fiddling with Xcode build settings and starting the Certificate/App ID/Provisioning Profile dance from scratch, I ended up at the same place, same error message, *App ID not available*.

In frustration, I pressed the `Try Again` button thinking it was futile. But it worked.

Answer (score 2):

I had this same issue in Xcode 7.3. To solve it I performed the following:

1. Deleted the provisioning profile on the developer portal website.
2. Created a new development provisioning profile manually on the
   portal website.
3. Added new profile in Xcode under Preferences ->
   Accounts -> Apple ID -> View Details. Attempting to just click the
   download button beside the new profile kept giving me an error. It
   was only when I clicked "download all" at the bottom that it finally
   downloaded and fixed everything.

Answer (score 2):

I had Distribution Provisioning for my Apple ID for the App Store only and still gave me that error: **An App ID with Identifier '' is not available. Please enter a different string**

I recently updated to Xcode 7.3 and probably that caused the issue. So what I did was creating iOS Development Provisioning by selecting all devices that I want to test in iOS Dev. Center (Member Center). Then Opened Xcode -> Preferences and under my account downloaded the newly created Development Provisioning for that App ID. When did that, the error disappeared.

Comment: the same issue which happened to me on yesterday,when I select to export for Ad-hoc deployment but still I couldn't do anything about that.I have tried  answer what you have updated.Could you please help me once again

Answer (score 2):

This seems to be a bit of a generic message. I'm sure many of the answers are correct. For me it was a mismatch between the entitlements and settings for the app in the member portal. My solution was this:

1. Verify your bundle id matches the portal
2. Verify your app in the portal has the same entitlements enabled as your project's entitlements file
3. Verify your provisioning profile is valid and edit/regen if not
4. In Xcode properties > Accounts double click on the account and tap the "download all" button
5. Clean
6. Try again

Comment: I have tried everything finally "download all" is the solution for me, Thanks:)

Answer (score 1):

com.domainName.AppName

this is the bundle identifier. based on this identifier only once can send push notifications and inapt purchases. so app made this as an unique id for app. So try with a new name as "com.domainName.YourName"

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue. I check all settings in Xcode all were proper. When I tried to upload app using Archive it was giving an error

```
"An App ID with Identifier 'com.myappname.yyy' is not available. Please enter a different string".
```

Then after I tried to upload app via "Application Loader" and got success!

Answer (score 1):

If not the AppId's business,just try to change the Team in TARGETS/identity to your company's team.

Answer (score 1):

I had generated the developer profile but not the distribution profile. I did that via the Apple Developer Member Center -> Certificates, Identifiers & Profiles -> Provisioning Profiles.

Next I downloaded these in Xcode via the Preferences->Accounts.

Answer (score 1):

With Xcode 7.3 I started seeing that issue.

Eugene Dubinin's solution did work, however it was causing issues with the same error if you're using App Groups.

It seems Xcode doesn't like at all you create the App IDs manually.
I succeeded at fixing the issue by first deleting the manually created App ID on the developer portal. Then I let Xcode 'Fix the issue' by itself. The App ID got created successfully and the problem was solved.

Answer (score 1):

For me the solution was to change the bundle identifier by replacing the period separator to dashes. I changed `com.mycompany.appname` to `com-mycompany-appname`.

Comment: This is not the appropriate format for bundle identifier. It is most likely a provisioning profile issue, such as a missing or expired provisioning profile.

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same issue after the Xcode 7.3 update and nothing worked. The fix is really simple, please follow the answer here, it worked for me: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34346556

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem since XCode 7.3. 
For my case, there was a _ in my AppId name and it didn't work even if the AppID was correct : com.mycompany.appname.

I had to edit the AppId in itunes member center to get this warning.

To resolve this bug, I renamed the AppId, generate a new certificate and new provisionning profiles.

Answer (score 1):

for me, i had to make sure an app with that bundle id was already created in the itunesconnect portal : /

Answer (score 1):

Nothing wrong with App Id in my case, but fix certificate and provisioning file first, then update to Xcode 7.3.1, clean, archive and submit, it works for me.

Answer (score 1):

For me, I was trying to create an app ID for an Enterprise app. The app ID had "xxx.ios.yyy" in it and it did not like the .ios. bit in the middle.  As soon as I removed the ".ios" part I was able to successfully register it.  This happened to me twice with two different app IDs of different length, and in each case, removing the ".ios" segment fixed the problem.

Comment: Not case sensitive either. I failed at having the suggested .iOS in the bundle path. Removing it fixed whatever was wrong.

Answer (score 1):

I am using Xcode 12.4. And I have been facing this issue with Free account. Now I added Bundle Id to my paid account. Went through above answers but no luck.

Following steps solved my issue. You may try once. thanks

Actual scenario so far I realized :

1. Main thing is when you build with Xcode then Bundle Id auto registered with account[free account]
2. Same Bundle Id is not working for new Paid account bcz of duplicacy
3. For free account it is not possible to remove app/Bundle Id from App Store Connect
4. So have to change Bundle Id for new Paid account.
5. If it was paid account then possible to remove Bundle Id from App Store Connect

Steps :

1. Sign with free account again on Xcode Team
2. Sync with Xcode which create provisioning profile to sync
3. Then change Bundle Id to  com.domain.appnamefree and sync with free account again
4. That means apple auto registered with this Bundle Id for this free account
5. Once this change got applied, the real bundle id became free and available
6. Then delete the free account from Xcode account
7. Now add paid account to Xcode Team
8. Change Bundle Id to com.domain.appname
9. And sync again so that apple recognised this Bundle Id for this Paid account

[image]

[image]

Comment: This seems like a good idea, but it didn't work for me. Or maybe I didn't do the same as you. What exactly to mean by 'sync with xcode'?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, when I use Xcode7.3 it. I solved the problem: I created a new profile select Ad Hoc, and then downloaded to Xcode.That‘s OK!

[image]

Comment: Worked for me :) Thx

Answer (score 0):

Me also got the same issue.

In my case i already registerd with my free account. We can't delete that app bundle id from our free account.

So i changed bundle id not app name and again i tried it's working.

Comment: I am facing same as you. thanks , it makes me to create a sense to change the bundle id. I was trying to delete the bundle id

Answer (score -3):

Downgrade to xcode 7.2.1 - it worked for me.

Comment: How can you downgrade when the only version available for download is 7.3 and older versions are no longer available?

Comment: MathiasC From here http://developer.apple.com/downloads/ you can download any older versions of Xcode

Chris Livdahl, I agree with you that is not a good idea but in delivery day we should try all solution to deliver the build. 
I don't want to do this way.

Comment: I don't understand this suggestion.  For me, this error message occurs in the *developer.apple.com* website...  changing the version of Xcode makes absolutely no difference.

Comment: That's not the resolution of asked question.