# An App ID with Identifier 'com.example.app.extention' is not available. Please enter a different string

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, provisioning-profile, app-id

I have tried to add extensions to my iOS app, both a today extension and an Apple Watch app. My app has been completed however when submitting my archive I got the error based on my bundle identifiers. I then removed the extensions, added them back, and attempted to resubmit. However, xcode now complained that my provisioning profiles cannot be signed.

> "An App ID with Identifier 'com.example.app.extention' is not
>   available. Please enter a different string."

I immediately went to the member center to see if an App ID already exists that prevents me from using it for my extensions. Nothing conflicted with the name, this is what was so bizarre to me. Shouldn't I be able to make the new ID if it doesn't conflict with an old ID? I also removed any provisioning profiles from previous extensions. Still, I could not add either `"com.example.app.extention"` or "`com.example.app.watchkitextension."`

I decided to just create new app IDs, following a new naming convention like `"com.example.app.extentions.watchkitextension."` or `"com.example.app.extentions.todayextention."` Everything worked fine, and built fine. I installed on my devices, things were good. My archive even was validated. However, upon submission I am given the error:

> ERROR ITMS-90347: "Bad bundle identifier. The bundle identifier
>   "xxx.yyy.zzz" of the application extension
>   xxx.app/Plugins/xxxExtension.appex should start with the application's
>   bundle identifier "xxx" and not contain more than one period "." after
>   the application bundle ID.

This means I have to use the naming convention `"com.example.app.extention"` that xcode and the member center will not allow me to create the proper IDs.

I am extremely frustrated, can someone please help. I cannot find a solution anywhere.

**EDIT**

It seemed that I was actually not able to use that identifier at all.

Also, I should note a couple of warnings for anyone with this message:

1) You cannot add anything before the extension of it includes a period, as in com.domain.app.extensions.extension won't work either. 
2) The automatics Swift 2 converter has a tendancy to change identifieres to more standard names and try to let xcode work out the provisioning profiles. Be careful of this!

The only fix I had was to change the identifier name for good. I personally used com.domain.app.todayextension. I got it to work then, but only after installing and adding the correct **provisioning profiles for development and distribution** through the **member center**. It appears to be a bug in Apple's system, or maybe we all have absolutely no idea how provisioning profiles work. I think the latter is probably what is true. Anyway, I hope that helps!

Comment: Hi, did you eventually found a solution for that? I'm having a similar issue now with my watchkitextention. Thanks

Comment: @goldengil It seemed that I was actually not able to use that identifier. Also, you cannot add anything before the extension of it includes a period, as in com.domain.app.extensions.extension won't work either. The only fix I had was to change the identifier name. I personally used com.domain.app.todayextension. I got it to work then, but only after installing and adding the correct provisioning profiles for development and distribution through the member center. It appears to be a bug in Apple's system.  I hope that helps!

Answer (score 28, accepted):

I found the solution from Apple developer forums.

Apple has just updated their Dev Center CGU. It seems that the app extension bundleId is stricter.

if your app bundleId format is : com.my.app

your app extension bundleId now have to be : com.my.app.XXX

Creating new appID and provisioning profile fix the issue.

Check this link https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/15712

Comment: But will that effect application which is already live or will it upload a new application to store with same name?

Comment: @XcodeNOOB for already live app you just have to rename your app ID

Comment: Somewhat late to the party... But this DID fix the issue for me :D

Comment: You idiots.  (I'm talking to Apple, rather than you !)   Fine, if Apple are going to make changes like that, fine... but at least display a *useful error message explaining the change*, rather than some misleading rubbish about it being "unavailable".  God, I hate this Xcode stuff.  They must really hate developers.

Answer (score 54):

**Version 7.3 (7D175)**

The Application ID Name should be same as application bundle identifier, if you application bundle identifier is com.abc.xyz than the application ID name for this bundle ID should be XC com abc xyz

**A name in any other format won't be seen by Xcode.**

***If your application is already on app store and you are submitting update than just change the app ID name accourding to above formate and it will work***

[image]

Comment: What!? are you sure about that?!

Comment: Um, holy cow, this actually worked for me too. Makes no sense to me.

Comment: @MatterGoal yes I am sure  about it, although make no sense.

Comment: Incredibly, this solved this ongoing persistently-returning problem for me too - great find @MuhammadImran

Comment: this should be marked as the correct answer (more info at http://stackoverflow.com/a/36343710/2609269)

Comment: According to the other SO thread, this is an Xcode bug that is fixed in 7.3.1.

Comment: Wow! This solution worked for me! Can anyone clarify why this happen ?

Comment: Its a bug in XCode 7.3 and is fixed in xCode 7.3.1

Comment: Only this worked for me today with the latest Xcode version.

Comment: great, exact solution

Comment: Just when you think iOS development couldn't get any weirder.

Answer (score 7):

**Xcode to 7.3**

I have encountered this issue when archiving and in my case, downloading all provisioning profiles on preferences cant fix this so I update it.

Try to check your app's Provisioning Profile on Member Center.

Go to Developer > Certificate, IDs & Profiles > Provisioning Profiles > All

Look for your app's Development and Distribution Profile, check if status is *Invalid* then **Edit**,

**Modify your profile contents and select the Generate button to save changes**

Finally, Go to Xcode> Preferences > [Apple account] > *View Details* and *Download All* to refresh your provisioning profiles

Clean. Build. Archive. Success !
Hope it helps :)

Comment: Worked well for me. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

I also encountered the same problem. Xcode7.2.1. 
[image]
Effective solution is：

[image]

Comment: Perfect. Selecting Team - "None" fixed it for me. I was able to rebuild, archive and submit it without any problem.

Comment: Sorry，I don't know for Xcode7.3. I  have not updated.

Answer (score 3):

Here is what worked for me on Xcode 7.3:

Check Devices in the Apple Developer member centre. Once a year you have the opportunity to reset the devices. After reseting devices you will notices your Xcode managed provisioning profile is invalid. To update this I went into Xcode > Accounts -> my Apple ID ->  View Details and downloaded all provisioning profiles. I then built to device and then downloaded the provisioning profiles again for good measure

Answer (score 1):

I can see lot's of great answers,

I tried a few of them but no luck, finally I used  **"Use local signing assets"** option to export ipa and it works for me.

Hopefully this will help someone.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I tried it with production provisioning profile, works for me.

Answer (score 0):

I had to delete the app id from the developer console and let XCode re-create the app id for me.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem when i upgraded my Xcode to 7.3 and it showed me the same error in every project. The simplest solution that i found was to just the remove the apple account from Xcode and add it again.

To remove just go to Xcode > Preferences > Select the account and click on - sign.

[image]

If in case this still doesn't work . Then perform a next step of downing your provisioning profile again and run it.

Hope this helps. All the best

Answer (score 0):

For a typical bundle ID such as com.mycompany.appname, the App ID name must be in this format:

XC com mycompany appname
a name in any other format won't be seen by Xcode.

Answer (score 0):

My problem was that when adding entitlements they never made it into the App Id in the member portal. Verify your app settings in the portal match your product entitlements file. Regen and download the provisioning profile as needed.

Answer (score 0):

**Xcode to 7.3**

I encountered the same problem after upgrading from 7.2 to 7.3.
In my case the fault was a **hyphenated domain** and AppID which worked in the past but stopped working in XCode 7.3.
I replaced the hyphen with a space in AppID (in Membercenter) and it worked again.

Answer (score 0):

I had almost the same problem, i was using Xcode 7.3 and trying to compile it but the build failed all the time, so the problem was for me that i needed to make a developer provisions profile and an appstore provisions profile for the same app so i could use fastlane to release it and build it in xcode.

After this i did the following:

1. Open Xcode
2. Xcode preferences
3. Open team
4. Download all missing profiles
5. Clean
6. Build
7. Run fastlane

Answer (score -1):

Update xCode - these issues normally trigger a thought in my head to update.  Normally fixes provisioning issue.  Worked for me.

Answer (score -2):

As far as I know, a bundle ID must have the form `com.yourCompany.yourApp`. App IDs are used to identify your app among all other millions of apps on the store and have to be unique.

Someone probably already created this ID `com.example.app.extention`. This is why you are seeing the error message.

You must used something unique, that identifies your company and your app or you and your app.