# An App ID with Identifier '' is not available. Please enter a different string (After TM restore)

Tags: ios, xcode, provisioning-profile

I'm getting the above error after restoring my machine to a recent Time Machine backup. This was working fine before restoring from the TM backup. I did go into the developer center and noticed that the provisioning profile for my phone had expired so I renewed it and downloaded the .mobileprovision file. I'm not sure if this is part of the problem and if so I'm not sure what to do with the .mobileprovision file...how/where to import it, etc. My bundle identifier is com.companyname.appname just like it was prior...no changes. In the project->Identity section in XCode, I do have the correct team set but there is an exclamation point beneath that indicating no matching provisioning files found for my iphone. 
Can someone please help me resolve this? Thanks!

Comment: check plist <key>CFBundleIdentifier</key>
 <string>com.xxx.app.xxx</string> (ur id)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [An App ID with Identifier 'com.example.app.extention' is not available. Please enter a different string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32346717/an-app-id-with-identifier-com-example-app-extention-is-not-available-please-e)

Comment: I found that thread while searching for a solution. It's similar but not the same thing. I'm still not sure what caused my issue, but renewing the provision profile opening it with XCode seemed to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

Resolved! I double clicked the .mobileprovision file that I downloaded, reopened XCode and the error in the identity section was no longer present...build completed successfully.