# App id is not available - TestFlight

Tags: ios, testflight, provisioning

I am trying to upload my app to the app store to test it with TestFlight.

I created in the Member Center the following items:
- Certificates Dev - Prod
- App ID (with same bundle identifier as in Xcode)
- Provisioning profiles for Ad Hoc & for Dev

I can test my app on my iPhone when it is connected to my laptop, now I am trying to share it to other testers, but after having archiving the app, I got the following error when uploading to the app store:

An App Id with identifier '..' is not available. Please enter a different string.

Any idea why this occurs?

I don't know what I did wrong..

Thanks.

Comment: may be this help:http://stackoverflow.com/a/33735750/4557505

Comment: Thanks :) But this is not for an extension of an iOS App. It is for iOS App itself with an app identifier like "com.example.company" that was accepted in the Member Center.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a record of the app to the itunes connect first. Then only you will be able to upload the app to the App Store and from there you will be able to add testers in the testflight.

If you have already created the record on the itunesconnect. Then please check your bundle identifier which must be same as the in the record created on itunesconnect.

If you want to test the app via testflight app.Then make the distribution profile rather than Ad-hoc profiles. For this, you will need to create a distribution certificate also.

Comment: I created the record of the app in Itunes Connect, but this does not resolve the issue. The same error is still there. The bundle identifier in Xcode is the same as the one from the App Id in the Member Center and the same as the identifier in iTunes Connect.

Comment: If you want to test the app via testflight app.Then make the distribution profile rather than Ad-hoc profiles. For this, you will need to create a distribution certificate also.

Comment: Thanks it works! Why do we need these ad-hoc profiles then?

Comment: Ad-hoc profiles are used for buisness purposes or organisation specific functionality app, like if you want the app to be run on limited devices(limited users or customers) then you can use the Ad-hoc profiles for distribution, rather than the distribution profiles. If you use Distribution profile you will make the application open for everybody via appstore.

Comment: So even for test flight testing for internal testers (no need to submit for review), you need a distribution profile rather than the ad-hoc profile?

Comment: Yes we don't need to submit for review for testflight. We can test it using testflight. After approvals, we will have to remove it from testing(testflight) from itunes connect. Then we have to select  that build to submit to appstore. Without stopping the testing process we won't be able to submit the app to the appstore.