# Bundle ID format is wrong?

Tags: ios, firebase, app-store-connect, provisioning-profile

I'm having a problem whereas I cannot submit my archive for beta testing due to this problem (keep in mind I've already got a build out for testing, uploaded a while ago):

> Xcode attempted to locate or generate matching signing assets and failed to do so because of the following issues.
>
> An App ID with identifier '' is not available. Please enter a different string

According to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32346717/an-app-id-with-identifier-com-example-app-extention-is-not-available-please-e), it seems that I should change my bundle ID from the format I am currently using: **com.my.app**, to the preferred format: **com.my.app.XXX**.

However, how can this be achieved? I'm using Firebase version 3 from Google as my backend provider, and I cannot seem to change the Bundle ID there, even if I would take the big step to create a whole new app in iTunes Connect due to not being able to changing the bundle ID.

My limitations (it seems):

- Can't change bundle ID at Firebase
- Can't change bundle ID with project in iTunes Connect.
- Can't delete app identifier in  member center because it's being used by the app listing in iTunes Connect.
- Can't delete app from iTunes Connect.

**Hence I'm a little stuck here**; what's the best way to dig out of this?

Comment: upgrade to Xoode 7.3.1.. or check this (regenerate certificate, refresh from Xcode..) https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/39714