# ERROR ITMS-90347: Bad bundle identifier

Tags: xcode, app-store, app-store-connect, archive, bundle-identifier

I have had the same problem. The apple ids I have used include com.appname, com.domain.appname, com.domain.appname.XXX. None of these bundle identifiers have worked. This is the error message I receive each time:

ERROR ITMS-90347: "Bad bundle identifier. The bundle identifier 'com.Signal' of the application extension Signal.app/PlugIns/Signal.appex should start with the application's bundle identifier 'com.Signal' and not contain more than one period “.” after the application's bundle ID."
ERROR ITMS-90347: "Bad bundle identifier. The bundle identifier 'com.Signal' of the application extension Signal.app/PlugIns/Signal.appex should start with the application's bundle identifier 'com.Signal' and not contain more than one period “.” after the application's bundle ID."

The domain is always drewbennett

appname: Signal

I have looked at all of these sites:

[An App ID with Identifier 'com.example.app.extention' is not available. Please enter a different string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32346717/an-app-id-with-identifier-com-example-app-extention-is-not-available-please-e)

https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/15712

[ERROR ITMS-90347: Bad bundle identifier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37821171/error-itms-90347-bad-bundle-identifier)

https://forums.adobe.com/thread/1369892

This is what I have struggled with for weeks. Please help if anyone has any answers.

Best,
Drew

Comment: did you find any solution for this ?