# Can't export IOS app archive from xcode for testflight

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store-connect, archive, testflight

I have an IOS app archive that I want to validate and export so that I can upload it to itunes connect for testing with internal users first, then eventually beta testers.  When I attempt to validate or export the archive I get a dialog titled "Failed to locate or generate matching signing assets:" with a message "Xcode attempted to locate or generate matching signing assests and failed to do so because of the following: **An App ID with Indentifier 'myAppBundleId' is not available. Please enter a different string.**"

In the Apple Developer Member Center I had long ago created an app id for my app, corresponding APN ssl certificates, and a corresponding provisioning profile.  Since I was unable to proceed as per the above dialog I tried giving my app a new bundle id, but when I then went to create an Archive with the new bundle ID it failed with a message "No matching provisioning profiles found".  I next tried creating a new App ID that had an ID that matched my new bundle ID.  When creating this new App ID I needed to enable push notifications, but it didn't show as enabled until I generated new SSL Certs.

I'm totally confused by all of this so this question really is about somehow finding clarity.  I have a ton of unanswered questions that come to mind as I try to navigate this confusing Apple ecosystem.  Some relate to the original issue and some are new questions that came up while trying things.  I'll list:

1. When I created a new App ID for the same App, and created SSL certificates, I just reused the the CSR that I had previously created for the other earlier app ID.  My thinking was that this might enable me to not actually have to do anything to my app or server since the CSR is the old one.  But I'm wondering if it would fail because the bundle IDs and app IDs are new? I can't recall if there was anything in the CSR that matched to the bundle ID or App ID.
2. Is the app ID the same as the bundle ID?
3. In Developer Member Center under iOS Provisioning Profiles, there is a column titled "status".  My older provisioning profiles say "Active (managed by Xcode)" and my newest ad-hoc provisioning profile says just "Active".  What is the difference between the two?  What makes a provisional profile managed by Xcode?
4. In itunes connect my bundle id is prefixed with the xcode bundle id suffix.  E.g. my bundle ID in Xcode is FirstName-LastName.AppName, but in itunes connect it puts AppName - FirstName-LastName.AppName.  what the heck?
5. Does Xcode ever automatically create an App ID?
6. I read that itunes connect's testflight doesn't require provisioning profiles for internal users, yet Xcode is complaining that "No Matching provisional profiles found" when I attempt to make the Archive with my new Bundle ID. Is a provisioning profile required for internal users or not?
7. Is there a good and up to date and comprehensive resource covering
   the essentials of things like app ids, bundle Ids, testflight,
   provisioning profiles, how provisioning profiles relate to app IDs,
   etc.  I'm left confused by Apples docs, and I've found one tutorial
   on youtube that was somewhat helpful and current but not
   comprehensive enough and didn't get me beyond the issues I'm
   encountering.  It was titled "Basically: iOS TestFlight Beta
   Testing" in case anyone reading this is interested.

   8. I'm confused by the message in Xcode "None of the valid provisioning profiles allowed the specified capabilities: Features: push, interAppAudio, and passbook".  My confusion is because in Developer Member Center these features are setup when creating an App ID not when creating a provisional profile.

Any help or advice is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue a few days ago, fixed it by removing all invalid provisioning profiles from my account on https://developer.apple.com/, then I created a new valid provisioning profile and added the newly created one in XCode. Then in build settings I selected the valid provisioning profile instead of auto, and I was able to export with no issues. Good luck :)

Comment: I deleted and recreated my app id, certificates and provisioning profiles.  Got everything back re-installed and running on my devices and still get this error when trying to export an archive.  I have three provisioning profiles, one for development, one for APNs, and one for distribution (ad-hoc).  And I  two app IDs: one specific and a *.

Comment: Sorry to hear that I couldn't resolve your issue. Check out this link, as it has more information and answers to your problem
[link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20565565/an-app-id-with-identifier-is-not-available-please-enter-a-different-string)

Comment: I've seen that link.  Solutions there didn't help.  Getting the error still.