# App ID with identifier not available when turning on remote notification

Tags: ios, xcode, provisioning-profile, app-id

I have an app which I've just submitted to the app store. In the developer portal it has push notification checked, however it's not yet configured.

[image]

I want to add Push notification capability to this app. I try to turn on Push in XCode Capability tab. There was a issue and I press fix issue, it said the ID is not available, though it it the ID for the app already available in the app store.

[image]

Also under the General tab:

[image]

Now what do I do to fix it? Despite having read "iOS Code Signing: Under The Hood" from Ray Wenderlich I'm still having a headache.

**EDIT:**

OK the accepted answer wasn't really it. I finally found the correct answer to this question from JRRevuelta's post in the Apple forum:

> Go to your Apple Developer "Certificates, Ids, Profiles", and under
>   your App IDs list find the App ID in question and,   If your App ID is
>   in the form: com.myDomain.MyApp Then the name in your App ID record
>   has to be: "XC com myDomain MyApp"   Don't ask me why, but it works.
>   (is the default name that XCode assigns when you create the record
>   from XCode), but for records that exist prior or that you created
>   directly in the Developer site, the name should be whatever you
>   want... but its not. Some glitch introduced in one of the latest XCode
>   releases.

Apparently this problem only surface in recent Xcode.

Comment: The bundle name which you're using for application should exist in member centre of developer account.

Comment: @JayeshSojitra It does!

Comment: @JayeshSojitra I actually have two developer accounts in my system. But I think I am choosing the right user base on the certificate.

Comment: Please check it out at here. http://stackoverflow.com/a/36589515/1404774

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the following steps it may solve your problem:

- manually removed INVALID iOS Team Provision Profile Managed by Xcode from Developer Portal
- manually created iOS Developer Provision profile
- Downloaded it via Xcode

For more information you can check: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36175175/4557505 answer, this answers the same issue which you are having

Comment: It doesn't say Invalid. It says active. It turns out that I (accidentally actually) removed the accounts for both user, added one of them back. And it worked! Thank you so much! I'm going to award the bounty to you anyway for linking to that page full of things to try. :D

Comment: Then it didn't work again...but I found out why from the Apple forum. "If your App ID is in the form: com.myDomain.MyApp
Then the name in your App ID record has to be: "XC com myDomain MyApp""

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to create the SSL certificates and set up a provisioning profile matching your needs. Assuming you already have an development provisioning profile for your app-id you just need to add the SSL certificate for development. When done testing add the certificate for production.

Comment: The complaint doesn't go away. For testing I should choose the development personal team right?

Comment: Yes! If you go to your target-> build settings and search for code signing identity, does it say developer or distribution?

Comment: It says iOS developer. If it helps, I actually have two developer accounts in my system. But I think I am choosing the right user base on the certificate.