# iOS must developement and distribution bundle identifier differ?

Tags: ios, xcode, provisioning-profile, ios-provisioning, app-id

I'm adding on Push Notification to an existing app on the App store. I've asked the question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36569548/app-id-with-identifier-not-available-when-turning-on-remote-notification) but I've not been able to resolve it. It keeps on telling me the identifier is not available. So I'm going back to simple questions first.

1. Do I keep on using the same ID or when developing do I need a different ID?
2. During development do I choose a different "team" there? (What exactly is that field anyway? Is that the certificate?)

[image]

**EDIT:**

I've finally am able solved my problem in my edit of the problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36569548/app-id-with-identifier-not-available-when-turning-on-remote-notification).

Comment: are you getting issue while upload app in App store?

Comment: @kb920 Nope. The App is already in the app store. Now I'm developing a newer version with push notification.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the same Id and team but you should **enable development and distribution certificate** in member centre if it is disabled or expired.

Comment: OK. Then I wonder why it doesn't work: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36569548/app-id-with-identifier-not-available-when-turning-on-remote-notification

Answer (score 0):

You can use single bundle identifier. But you need to generate development certificate with push notification feature turned on. Then you won't be face any issue.

Update bundle identifier as shown below in Member centre.

Select identifier from Member centre.

[image: Select identifier from development centre]

Then edit identifier and enable push notification from there.

[image]

Then develop development certificate for it and install in machine.

Then retry to fix issue using capabilities. It should be working.

Comment: The push notification was enabled before I sent my prior version to the app store. But it wasn't configured. I actually already did the steps you described. What do you do with the downloaded certificate? Just add to keychain? The issue still persist as long as I use the same identifier.