# My Bundle ID is now invalid

Tags: xcode, xcode7

The bundle ID I use on iTunes connect for an existing app is now invalid.
When I first opened Xcode 7.3 asked for a "Fix" below the team button
[image]

When I clicked it, it said "Reset" and I did it.

Now when I try to "Fix" it again
[image]
This pops up even though this is my Bundle ID already. I need to relink this so I can update my app. Thank you!

Comment: refer this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20565565/an-app-id-with-identifier-is-not-available-please-enter-a-different-string

Comment: @DarjiJigar It is an already existing app on the AppStore though with the Bundle ID already established, but now it is invalid.

Comment: you select perfect team name

Comment: @DarjiJigar My team name is already correct.

Comment: check out in apple member center weather the bundle id exist and it is enabled / active. If it is not enabled just edit it to enable it

Comment: @TysonVignesh The App ID exists in my member center, Game Center and  In-App Purchases are enabled.

Comment: go to preferences > account settings > select your team> view details > download all

Comment: @TysonVignesh I have to remake all of the files because I deleted them all because they were expired or not working properly because of the problem above. I don't remember which provision to even make for it to work properly.

Comment: Are you saying about the provisioning certificates?

Comment: @TysonVignesh Yes, I deleted them because they were not working with me, also not fixing the problem that the app bundle id is taken even though it matches the provisioning profile and the bundle used in iTunes connect. I also tried making and downloading new ones. I tried a new AppStore distribution provision certificate/ file and it did not work. I do not know how to get it synced up again without renaming my bundle ID and probably deleting it off the AppStore and reuploading it as a new app which would not make sense because existing users would not know there is an update.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/109505/discussion-between-tyson-vignesh-and-joe-mancini).