# Validating error after archive in iOS

Tags: ios, macos, validation, publish, archive

I am trying to upload this ionic project for iOS devices using Xcode 7.3. I successfully created all the certificates and app ids and then archived. But after that, when I click on the validate option I get an error, which I do not understand!
The error says:

```
 Failed to locate or generate matching signing assets:
   Xcode attempted to locate or generate matching signing assets and failed to do so because of the following issues.
    An App ID with identifier 'com.*****.******' is not available. Please enter a different string.
```

THankx in advance

Comment: do you have an app on iTunesConnect?

Comment: please check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36598957/an-app-id-with-identifier-is-not-available-please-enter-a-different-string-whil/36618791#36618791
and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20565565/an-app-id-with-identifier-is-not-available-please-enter-a-different-string?lq=1

Comment: Yes I have it on iTunesConnect

Answer (score 0):

I got the same issue with upload from Xcode7.3. Before xcode7.3 that we dont need to create an app on iTunesConnect and we can create an IPA file and all the things. But i did Fix this issue by following:

- Open iTunesConnect and login with Apple-id password.
- Create new iOS app and select the identifier that we used in our Xcode project.
- After that you just need go in Xcode and select device and create an archive.
- Do the same step that you did before and the error goes away.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same issue. Check the following steps :

1) Check if the bundle ID of your project in Xcode is same as the bundle ID associated with your AppID in Member Center.

2) Make sure you are selecting the correct Distribution Certificate and provisioning profile.

3) Make sure you have created an app on iTunes connect. Crosscheck the bundle ID there as well.

Now try to archive and validate again. Hope this solves your problem.