# How do I request a certificate with xcode8?

Tags: xcode, xcode8

From the website: "Xcode is the easiest way to request certificates. Connect your device to your Mac and click Use for Development in Xcode's Organizer window. Sign in with the Apple ID associated with your iOS Developer Program membership and Xcode will automatically generate your certificates." The problem is, in the "organizer" window there is only "Archive" and "Crashes", even though I do have a connected device.

Comment: You may be reading something that is older, the organizer window used to contain the devices manager in earlier versions of Xcode. Try the Devices window.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion; however, that window only contains "view device logs" and "take screenshot".

Comment: What you're trying to do may also be automatic now or part of the Xcode installation. Can you create a template "Cocoa Application" macOS application and then just press the "play" button. Based on your question, I'm inferring that you are trying to do macOS development as opposed to iOS dev.

Comment: I'm trying to put my iOS app on the app store.

Comment: So you're first trying to run it on your iPhone?

Comment: No i just need to put it on the app store. And now I ran into this issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20565565/an-app-id-with-identifier-is-not-available-please-enter-a-different-string (which the solution doesn't solve)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/149333/discussion-between-allen-humphreys-and-pete).