# issue while registering bundle id to appstore certificates and id

Tags: ios, app-store, xcode10, bundle-identifier

[image]

i using `10.2.1 (10E1001)` and i am registering bundle id to my account but i am getting error like below

i have refer some answers but it can't solve my problem here is answers

here is the link which i have tried

1. [An App ID with Identifier '' is not available. Please enter a different string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20565565/an-app-id-with-identifier-is-not-available-please-enter-a-different-string/36589136)
2. [An App ID with Identifier '' is not available. Please enter a different string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20565565/an-app-id-with-identifier-is-not-available-please-enter-a-different-string/36375131)

Comment: you have to enter different bundle id because `com.Hemshub.SMSApp` is taken. it's already registered by someone.

Comment: If you have created an app with this bundle id in App Store connect, make sure that you have logged into the same developer account in Xcode.

Answer (score 1):

the bundle identifier must be unique , change it to a unique one , the error will be ok .