# An App ID with identifier "com.companyName.xyz.NotificationServiceExtension" is not available

Tags: ios, xcode, testflight, provisioning-profile, bundle-identifier

We have a project with prod target with Bundle Identifier `com.companyName.X` & stage target with Bundle Identifier `com.companyName.Y`

We have implemented Push Notification and added a Notification Service Extension file.

To upload the stage build to test flight, we have named the Notification Service Extension bundle identifier as `com.companyName.Y.NotificationServiceExtension`

Now, to upload the stage build to testflight, in requiring the certificate/provisioning profile for this stage service extension.

When I try to create an identifier in the apple developer portal with the App ID `com.companyName.Y.NotificationServiceExtension`, I get an error saying

> An App ID with identifier `'com.companyName.Y.NotificationServiceExtension'` is not available. Please try a different string

Can anyone tell me what am I doing wrong here?

Just FYI, I have an identifier created for the prod version i.e `com.companyName.X.NotificationServiceExtension` and it can be uploaded properly.

Comment: Is `com.companyName.Y.NotificationServiceExtension` the exact identifier that you are using? If so, it's probably already been used by some other dev account. You will need to choose a different identifier.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [An App ID with Identifier '' is not available. Please enter a different string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20565565/an-app-id-with-identifier-is-not-available-please-enter-a-different-string)

Answer (score 1):

Hey so you said here:

> *To upload the stage build to test flight, we have named the Notification Service Extension bundle identifier as
> com.companyName.Y.NotificationServiceExtension*

You must of already created the bundleID for the App then? whenever you create a push certificate you must sign it to a bundleID. If thats the case check what bundleID its hooked up to and then either change it or create the app with that bundleID.